# How to pass data from plugin B to Plugin A

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to pass Data From Plugin B class to Plugin A class. when Plugin A is depend on Plugin B.

Comment: When B has to transfer data to A; then B depends on A, not vice versa.

Comment: In Plugin A, i have a tree viewer and In Plugin B, I have a registration form. so, tree viewer is depend on registration form details. when i pass value in registration form it will display in tree viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ghostCat, If B needs to pass data to A, then B is depend on A.

But I think there is a workaround, you can define an interface C, A implements C, and B uses the interface C, then B is depend on C rather than A.

```
interface C {
    passMeSomeData(Object o);
}

class A implements C{
    //... some other code
    public passMeSomeData(Object o){
        //do some thing
    }
}

class B {
    //... some other code
    void oneMethod(){
        C c = methodToGetA();
        c.passMeSomeData();
    }
}
```

Technically, you can resolve any cyclic dependency by using interfaces. But do not do it unless it is completely needed.